# Скрытие пунктов меню в JMenu

Tags: java, swing

Пытаюсь создать главное меню. Использую javax.swing.JMenu. Но требуется в некоторых случаях скрывать отдельные элементы (JMenuItem). При событии показа пунктов меню устанавливаю новое значение visible. Но в итоге получается, что набор видимых пунктов меню верный, но размер всего popup-menu не пересчитывается. Т.е. периодически получается, что либо много пунктов теснятся на небольшой панели, либо наоборот, мало пунктов на большую панель. Что можно сделать, чтобы размеры пересчитывались?
Событие ловлю так:

```
menuitem.addPropertyChangeListener("ancestor", new PropertyChangeListener() {
  public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent e) {
     // update visibility
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Никогда не сталкивался с подобным. А вы уверены, что у вас нет смешения потоков? Какой код меняет эту пропертю? В каклом потоке он выполняется?

UPD: учитывая ниже сказанное, обнаружен безопасный способ смены видимости:

```
mainMenu.addMenuListener(new MenuListener() {
    public void menuSelected(MenuEvent e) {
        for(JMenuItem item : items)
            item.setVisible(rnd.nextBoolean());
    }
....
```

При такой реализации указанный дефект не проявляется.

Comment: Приложение однопоточное. Всё выполняется в EDT. Проперть меняется тогда, когда у пункта меню появляется родитель.

Comment: Хм. Должно быть, это какой-то баг, связанный с тем, что смена видимости как-то мешает просчёту лэйаута в момент добавления. Надо либо отказаться от идеи использования этой свойства, либо попытаться вызвать validate/revalidate для меню, но не совсем ясно, когда можно это сделать. В идеале, следует избегать явных ревалидаций..

Comment: Кстати, я воспроизвёл эту дурную ситуацию. У меня появилось пустое меню, предназначенное на самом деле для одного элемента. 
Это стало воспроизводиться только при прослушивании этой проперти для каждого элемента меню. Вообще, использование этой проперти - довольно странная техника, так что не удивительно, что выплываются странные косяки..

Comment: Спасибо. То, что лучше не использовать слушателей пропертей - это точно. Но у меня такая система, что в ней есть специальный menu-handler, который должен был работать, как с JPopupMenu, так и с JMenu, иначе придется писать разные слушатели, как выяснилось. А если б возможно было использовать слушатель для проперти, то код был бы выделен в базовый класс. Я пытался в обработчике проперти писать и doLayout, и validate/revalidate, updateUI, но ничего не помогло. С MenuListener заработало.